# PHP source code shown instead of executed

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I try to retrieve information from my MySQL database and show it on my web page, the page shows the source instead.

The code source start after the `->fecth()`. I think that my WAMP is not setup correctly or the obvious one: "I did something wrong somewhere".
I am not looking for an upgrade but just for corrections.

```
   <?
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
        $rep = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM membre');

        while($data = $rep->fetch()) 
         {
              echo $data['nom'];
         }
   ?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What's not working properly. This is a bit unclear in your question.

Comment: Looks like you're not loading from the webserver or Apache PHP is not running.

Comment: Funny why that is the output and not more if php is not activated

Comment: no errors, just query('SELECT * FROM membre');

        while($data = $rep->fetch()) 
         {
              echo $data['nom'];
         }
   ?> is shown when i start the page

Comment: Because <? starts a HTML tag and the > before query() closes the tag.  The rest is text output.  View source and you'll see it all.

Comment: the webserver not working is my first guess but whenever i start other php pages on my wamp it work. it look like php doesn't recognize PDO

Comment: it was the tag, thanks

Comment: @JayBlanchard no, it's not a typo. It's PHP crap called "short tag". one of many nonsenses in PHP. Unfortunately.

Comment: I know it is valid @MarcinOrlowski, but I'm wondering if the OP made a typo here.

Comment: If it is valid then how can it be a typo at the same time? -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can't configured your php for accept `<?` open tag, try to use `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

You might need a complete PHP tag:

```
<?php
```

You might need to have a "LoadModule" statement in your Apache config file.

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache22/libphp5.so
```

Last, quite often this is the problem --- you need AddHandler:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php  .php
```

This is often system dependent.  Perhaps your hosting company can help?

Comment: OP is not using a hosting company, this is on WAMP.

Comment: Then he'll have to fix it himself, I guess ... ;)

Which is why I gave him three places to look ... :)

Comment: thanks i wasn't sure if it was the wamp messing up or my code had a problem. i'll try to figure it out then. thanks